# A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'. When generate debug apk file in React native

Tags: react-native

Create android/app/src/main/assets/  this folder

#react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/

#cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug

run this command but i got the error

=============================================================================================
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/var/www/html/reactNative/wurthA/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/build.gradle' line: 89
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/var/www/html/reactNative/wurthA/android/local.properties'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
=============================================================================================[image]

Comment: Have a try by opening the project in the android studio and run

Comment: No i am not install android studio . i am running project using expo web browser and tunnel

Comment: if you are using expo the how can you run react native commands ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install an Android SDK and point to it in ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable. More details here https://gist.github.com/venkateshshukla/9736261

```
SDK - Software Development Kit
    a. Download android sdk tools from 
       http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
    b. Extract it to a directory say android_sdk
    c. Set the environment variable ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to point to android_sdk
    d. Add the directories android_sdk/tools and android_sdk/platform-tools
       to your path
NDK - Native Development Kit
    a. Download android ndk tools from
       http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html 
    b. Extract is to a directory say android_ndk
    c. Set the environment variable ANDROID_NDK_ROOT to point to android_ndk
    d. Add the directories android_ndk to your path

For linux systems the environment and path can be set by adding the 
following lines to ~/.bashrc file

export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/path/to/android_sdk
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/path/to/android_ndk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_NDK
```

Comment: Yes i install android/sdk and now generating the debug apk  got error   > Task :expo-permissions:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
/node_modules/react-native-unimodules/node_modules/expo-permissions/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/permissions/requesters/BackgroundLocationRequester.kt: (12, 50): Unresolved reference: R

Comment: I think you have outdated build tools. Check here https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/10283